# Order Data from three different models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have three models ie image, datafiles and video. I want to fetch the latest content by a user from all the three models.

One very bad of doing this can be:

```
  images = User.find(8).images
  videos = User.find(8).videos
  data_files = User.find(8).data_files
```

All the content:

```
 all_content = images + videos + data_files
 all_content.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page=> per_page)
```

How can do this in just one query to make the code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's a good idea to have a `Content` model which connects a user to his contents. Something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # Remember the contentable_type and contentable_id columns
  belongs_to :contentable, :polymorphic => true
end

# Similar relations for Image/File models
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :content, :as => :contentable
  belongs_to :user, :through => :content
end

# Then to fetch the last contents from the user
Content.where(:user_id => 8).order('created_at DESC')
       .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page=> per_page)
```

It's just a proof of concept, you could even go with [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) if you prefer, it depends on the attributes each of your content model has, probably it's the better thing given these object usually contains a title, a body, a link to the content, an url and similar stuff and few differences.

If you go with STI you need to define a base model (`Content` in this case) with the common attributes and several other model for each of your content model (e.g. `Image` or `Video`). These models inherit from the Content model. Remember to have a `contents` table in your DB with a `type` column (which will contain the string with the type of content, e.g. 'Video') and all the columns for the child models (yes, if you use this approach all the data will go in a *single table*).

**UPDATE**: The Single Table Inheritance approach has several pros, e.g. you get all the contents' data in one query, the previous solution is good for sorting but you still need to get the Video, and other specific data with other queries:

```
# The contents table has a type string column and
# all the specific models's columns
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# Video class inherit from Content (a Video is a Content!)
class Video < Content
end
```

In this case if you want all the user's content you can use `user.contents` and you'll get an array of the specific objects (Video, Image and so on) depending of their type.
You can also get just the images or videos with something like this `Video.all`

Of course these are just ideas, the real implementation depends on your problem and requirements.

Comment: Hey, I got the thing, you are talking about polymorphic relationships. I can't use that cause my models are not having common data columns. But ya I can still store just ids to get the polymorphic stuff.

Comment: The first solution I showed doesn't require much common data among the models, you just store the reference to the specific model (e.g. Video) in a base model (Content) so you can fetch all the contents querying the `contents` table.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like this in the User model:

```
def resources
  (images + videos + data_files).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
end
```

then call

```
User.find(8).resources.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page=> per_page)
```

Comment: Will it fetch all the records first then do things? I think yes? what say?

Comment: yeah it fetches all the records first then sorts them.

Comment: Thats a bad approach. Assume if there are some big chunk of data for a user this will take a lot of time.

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you're trying to do here. If you wanted to get the "latest" entries of a model, you could do something like images = Images.where("user_id = ? and created_at > ?", User.find(8).id, 5.days.ago )

Comment: I have three models and I want to fetch lastest 12 entries from all the three models. 12 from 3, not 12 + 12 + 12 from each. It can be anything like 3 images, 2 data files or 7 videos or some other combination based upon user's activity what he has uploaded. Images.where("user_id = ? ", 8).paginate..... will give me images right? Now what I want to do is the same query but in three models to get the output.

Comment: Ok I understand now. My initial suggestion would be get the latest 12 items from each model like I described above (just add .limit(12)), put them all into an array, order by created_at, and then reduce that array down to 12. That will give the desired result and wouldn't take long. That's the most efficient way I can think of as far as a query is concerned.